# Python argparse print version and exit

Tags: python, argparse

Here is my code.

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="prog")

parser.add_argument("-v", "--version", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("filename")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.version:
  print_version_and_exit()
```

If I run `prog --version` it should print the version and exit, But currently, it's failing with the following error, because of the positional argument.

```
usage: prog [-h] [-v] filename
prog: error: the following arguments are required: filename
```

How do I make positional arguments not required if the option version entered?

Comment: In the docs, under the `action` header you'll find "version".  This displays and exits, much like the `help`.  Your approach only exits after parsing, so it still requires the `filename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question based on @hpaulj's comment.

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="prog")

parser.add_argument("-v", "--version", action="version", version="v0.1.0")
parser.add_argument("filename")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Adding version action would do the trick